# Why reduce performs much sub-optimal than recur in this case?

Tags: clojure

One of intuitive ways to calculate π in *polynomial sum* looks like below,

> π = ( 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ... ) × 4

The following function ρ or ρ' denotes the *polynomial sum*, and the consumed time τ to calculate the π is measured respectively,

```
 (defn term [k]                                                                                                        
   (let [x (/ 1. (inc (* 2 k)))]                                                                                       
     (if (even? k)                                                                                                     
       x                                                                                                               
       (- x))))                                                                                                        

 (defn ρ [n]                                                                                                           
   (reduce                                                                                                             
     (fn [res k] (+ res (term k)))                                                                                     
     0                                                                                                                 
     (lazy-seq (range 0 n))))                                                                                          

 (defn ρ' [n]                                                                                                          
   (loop [res 0 k 0]                                                                                                   
     (if (< k n)                                                                                                       
       (recur (+ res (term k)) (inc k))                                                                                
       res)))                                                                                                          

 (defn calc [P]                                                                                                        
   (let [start (System/nanoTime)                                                                                       
         π (* (P 1000000) 4)                                                                                           
         end (System/nanoTime)                                                                                         
         τ (- end start)]                                                                                              
     (printf "π=%.16f τ=%d\n" π τ)))                                                                                   

 (calc ρ)                                                                                                              
 (calc ρ')
```

The result tells that ρ is about half more time spent than ρ', hence the underlying [reduce](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduce) performs much sub-optimal than [recur](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/recur) in **this** case, but why?

Comment: There is no point in using lazy-seq call in p. If you want to produce a lazy sequence of terms, you can use iterate function or lazy-seq with cons

Comment: in fact, on my machine `p` performs 15-20% faster that `p'`.. clojure 1.10, nrepl.. i guess, one invocation is not representative, with warmup/jit compilation and stuff.. you could at least call it `n` times and observe: `(dotimes [_ 20] (calc p))`. first time is generally slower than average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your code and using a more accurate timer shows there is no significant difference. This is to be expected since both `loop/recur` and `reduce` are very basic forms and we would expect them to both be fairly optimized.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [criterium.core :as crit] ))

(def result (atom nil))

(defn term [k]
  (let [x (/ 1. (inc (* 2 k)))]
    (if (even? k)
      x
      (- x))))

(defn ρ [n]
  (reduce
    (fn [res k] (+ res (term k)))
    0
    (range 0 n)) )

(defn ρ' [n]
  (loop [res 0 k 0]
    (if (< k n)
      (recur (+ res (term k)) (inc k))
      res)) )

(defn calc [calc-fn N]
  (let [pi (* (calc-fn N) 4)]
    (reset! result pi)
    pi))
```

We measure the execution time for both algorithms [using Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium):

```
(defn timings
  [power]
  (let [N (Math/pow 10 power)]
    (newline)
    (println :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (spyx N)
    (newline)
    (crit/quick-bench (calc ρ N))
    (println :rho @result)
    (newline)
    (crit/quick-bench (calc ρ' N))
    (println :rho-prime N @result)
    (newline)))
```

and we try it for 10^2, 10^4, and 10^6 values of N:

```
(dotest
  (timings 2)
  (timings 4)
  (timings 6))
```

with results for 10^2:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
N => 100.0

Evaluation count : 135648 in 6 samples of 22608 calls.
             Execution time mean : 4.877255 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 647.723342 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 4.438762 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 5.962740 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 31.6928 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
:rho 3.1315929035585537

Evaluation count : 148434 in 6 samples of 24739 calls.
             Execution time mean : 4.070798 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 68.430348 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 4.009978 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 4.170038 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns
:rho-prime 100.0 3.1315929035585537
```

with results for 10^4:

```
:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
N => 10000.0

Evaluation count : 1248 in 6 samples of 208 calls.
             Execution time mean : 519.096208 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 143.478354 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 454.389510 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 767.610509 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 65.1517 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
:rho 3.1414926535900345

Evaluation count : 1392 in 6 samples of 232 calls.
             Execution time mean : 431.020370 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 14.853924 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 420.838884 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 455.282989 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 13.8889 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
:rho-prime 10000.0 3.1414926535900345
```

with results for 10^6:

```
:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
N => 1000000.0

Evaluation count : 18 in 6 samples of 3 calls.
             Execution time mean : 46.080480 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.039714 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 45.132049 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 47.430310 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns
:rho 3.1415916535897743

Evaluation count : 18 in 6 samples of 3 calls.
             Execution time mean : 52.527777 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 17.483930 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 41.789520 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 82.539445 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.165947 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 81.7010 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
:rho-prime 1000000.0 3.1415916535897743
```

Note that the times for rho and rho-prime flip-flop for the 10^4 and 10^6 cases.  In any case, don't believe or worry much about timings that vary by less than 2x.

---

### Update

I deleted the `lazy-seq` in the original code since `clojure.core/range` is already lazy.  Also, I've never seen `lazy-seq` used without a `cons` and a recursive call to the generating function.

Re `clojure.core/range`, we have the docs:

> range
>
> Returns a lazy seq of nums from start (inclusive) to end (exclusive),
>   by step, where start defaults to 0, step to 1, and end to infinity.
>   When step is equal to 0, returns an infinite sequence of start. When
>   start is equal to end, returns empty list.

In the source code, it calls out into the Java impl of clojure.core:

```
  ([start end]
   (if (and (instance? Long start) (instance? Long end))
     (clojure.lang.LongRange/create start end)
     (clojure.lang.Range/create start end)))
```

& the Java code indicates it is chunked:

```java
    public class Range extends ASeq implements IChunkedSeq, IReduce {
      private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 32;
      <snip>
```

Comment: Your test removed the `lazy-seq` wrapper from the reduce version, which I would expect to be a big part of the slowdown. Did you find similar timings with the original code as written?

Comment: Since it was wrapping `range` which is already lazy, I just deleted it to remove unknown variables.  Same with some of the other mods.

Comment: But range isn't "lazy". It's magic reducer dust. If you are going to tell the OP that there's no performance difference in the code posted, you should actually measure the code posted, not a simpler version that you think is equivalent. Explaining the effect of those "unknown variables" is the whole point of answering "why is this code slow?".

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to other answers.
Performance can be significantly increased in you eliminate math boxing (original versions were both about 25ms). And variant with `loop/recur` is 2× faster.

```clj
(set! *unchecked-math* :warn-on-boxed)

(defn term ^double [^long k]
  (let [x (/ 1. (inc (* 2 k)))]
    (if (even? k)
      x
      (- x))))

(defn ρ [n]
  (reduce
    (fn [^double res ^long k] (+ res (term k)))
    0
    (range 0 n)))

(defn ρ' [^long n]
  (loop [res (double 0) k 0]
    (if (< k n)
      (recur (+ res (term k)) (inc k))
      res)))

(criterium.core/quick-bench
    (ρ 1000000))
Evaluation count : 42 in 6 samples of 7 calls.
             Execution time mean : 15,639294 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 371,972168 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 15,327698 ms ( 2,5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 16,227505 ms (97,5%)
                   Overhead used : 1,855553 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16,6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16,6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 13,8889 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
=> nil
(criterium.core/quick-bench
    (ρ' 1000000))
Evaluation count : 72 in 6 samples of 12 calls.
             Execution time mean : 8,570961 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 302,554974 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 8,285648 ms ( 2,5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 8,919635 ms (97,5%)
                   Overhead used : 1,855553 ns
=> nil
```

Comment: I also tested other *reduce* variants. All of them can't catch up with *loop/recur*. The math unboxing helps the latter speed up much more than the former.

Comment: @sof if you use `range` in `loop/recur` then it will be slower than any `reduce` version :-)
```
  (loop [res (double 0) ks (range 0 n)]
    (if-some [k (first ks)]
      (recur (+ res (term k)) (rest ks))
      res))```
Execution time mean : 46,117215 ms

Comment: Impedance mismatch on the mixture of PP and FP?

Comment: Obviously calculating `k` is less expensive than taking it from sequence :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the improved version to be more representative. Seemingly, the performance varies from case to case but not by that much.

```
 (defn term [k]                                                                                                        
   (let [x (/ 1. (inc (* 2 k)))]                                                                                       
     (if (even? k)                                                                                                     
       x                                                                                                               
       (- x))))                                                                                                        

 (defn ρ1 [n]                                                                                                          
   (loop [res 0 k 0]                                                                                                   
     (if (< k n)                                                                                                       
       (recur (+ res (term k)) (inc k))                                                                                
       res)))                                                                                                          

 (defn ρ2 [n]                                                                                                          
   (reduce                                                                                                             
    (fn [res k] (+ res (term k)))                                                                                      
    0                                                                                                                  
    (range 0 n)))                                                                                                      

 (defn ρ3 [n]                                                                                                          
   (reduce + 0 (map term (range 0 n))))                                                                                

 (defn ρ4 [n]                                                                                                          
   (transduce (map term) + 0 (range 0 n)))                                                                             

 (defn calc [ρname ρ n]                                                                                                
   (let [start (System/nanoTime)                                                                                       
         π (* (ρ n) 4)                                                                                                 
         end (System/nanoTime)                                                                                         
         τ (- end start)]                                                                                              
     (printf "ρ=%8s n=%10d π=%.16f τ=%10d\n" ρname n π τ)))                                                            

 (def args                                                                                                             
   {:N (map #(long (Math/pow 10 %)) [4 6])                                                                             
    :T 10                                                                                                              
    :P {:recur ρ1 :reduce ρ2 :mreduce ρ3 :xreduce ρ4}})                                                                

 (doseq [n (:N args)]                                                                                                  
   (dotimes [_ (:T args)]                                                                                              
     (println "---")                                                                                                   
     (doseq [kv (:P args)] (calc (key kv) (val kv) n))))
```